# Conflict when squash pull to one commit

Tags: git

As I want to keep **one commit per pull request**, here is how things go:

1. Checkout from to branch `feature` and do some work.
2. Work is done. I `stash` my code, `pull` new code from `origin/master` to get the latest version.
3. `git stash apply` to bring back the work and resolve conflicts.
4. `git commit --amend -m "New message"`.
5. `git push origin feature`.

Yet Github pull request to merge `feature` to `main` still displays the *same conflicts* I had when local code is stashed into the master one.
What should I do in this case to get everything up and running, while keeping it at only one commit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the purpose of one commit per PR ?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Just my company's convention to keep things clean.

Comment: I don't see any reason for that. PR are aggregates for commits. Actually, I don't imagine how I could do all my work in single commit. What if you are mid work and going on holiday? You must to push to remote anyway for anyone ese to be able to see those changes. That's wrong approach and recommend not to use it.

Comment: @trannguyen61 can you please clarify, you pull from `origin/master` into your feature branch? You don't pull the remote changes into your local `master`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Squash And Merge in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338593/how-to-use-squash-and-merge-in-github)

Comment: @Joe I guess no. The topic you mentioned is about squashing commits on Github, while I still face conflicts on Github and am not able to merge at all. Fixing conflicts on Github would lead to another commit, which is something I'm trying to avoid. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @mnestorov I do both. Neither pulling from `origin/master` nor from `local/master` works and Github still shows conflicts.

Comment: I mean I pull `origin/master` to both `local/master` and `local/feature`. I also tried not pulling `origin/master` directly to `local/feature`, but merging from `local/master` but it didn't help. I guess my last comment was quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you overwrite a merge commit.

## Example

Let say you have a `main` branch and a `feature` branch.

```
# main branch
* 6ce0740 - This commit only exist on main
* b82d267 - Another Commit
* e168387 - Initial Commit

# feature branch
* 1a6ac14 - This commit only exist on feature
* b82d267 - Another Commit
* e168387 - Initial Commit
```

After you run `git merge main` on `feature`, we would have this commit history.

```
# feature branch
* ae70e9a - Merge branch 'main' into feature
* 6ce0740 - This commit only exist on main
* 1a6ac14 - This commit only exist on feature
* b82d267 - Another Commit
* e168387 - Initial Commit
```

At this point, merging `feature` into `main` would just require a simple [fast-forward commit](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge).

But instead, you said you squash all commits into one before pushing. That could lead to conflicts since git will now have to compare these 2 branches instead of just moving the HEAD pointer.

## In conclusion

The best option if you want to keep the commit history clean is to use GitHub or GitLab "Merge and Squash" feature, which will squash all commits into one when you decide to merge to `main`.

However, if you **insisted** that you want to squash all commits into one before pushing, consider pulling using rebase. However, this is NOT best practice.

```
git pull origin main --rebase
# squash commit by git rebase -i or something
git push --force-with-lease
```